# Visudo syntax error when editing a sudoers file

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I am adding this file

```
cat /etc/sudoers.d/myuser

myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl start compose-service, /usr/bin/systemctl status compose-service
```

where `compose-service` is a custom `systemd` service I have created / enabled.

However the `visudo` command informs me there is a syntax error (on line 1)

Is something wrong with the statement above?

Working on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Is that the only line in your sudoers file?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Ubuntu 20.04. As has been asked, are there other lines in the file?

Comment: There were no other lines but the problem since to have gone away after adding a newline character at the end of the line above

Comment: If it's on line 1 than it sounds like it is a hidden character. Delete the file and try again.

Comment: @pkaramol please add that as an answer. Also note that it is quite common and normal. Text files need to end with a trailing newline (at least for certain definitions of "text files") and various programs will choke if they can't find a final newline.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it needed a **newline character** at the end of this line

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl start compose-service, /usr/bin/systemctl status compose-service
```

As @terdon points out in a relevant comment

> Text files need to end with a trailing newline (at least for certain definitions of "text files") and various programs will choke if they can't find a final newline